# How to obtain data on one table with matching columns through 3 tables using php?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've tried to find a clear answer for this nooby questions. This should be an easy one for you.

**To make my question clearer please see:**

[image]

The 3 tables are a basic example - but the contents are variable data that is automatically stored.

I have access to **table_1 User_id**. As the other two tables contain generated variables which I do not know the contents.

I want to match the data available to get the contents of price for the **user_id : '35'** stored in **table_3**. (Circled in red)

To do this I must correlate the matching data between tables to get the end result.

I'm not sure the best practice to implement this.

I'm guessing a further adaption of `$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM table_1";`

*As I am learning could do with some help to implement this simple problem into my own tables - many thanks in advance.*

Comment: That is a standard join query. Please take a SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to program using PHP it is highly recommended that you also learn to SQL. I say that because 80% (don't quote me on this) of PHP applications are built with a database in the back end. But enough of that, let's get to your question.

---

SQL has a nice way of combining data using the `JOIN` keyword. What it does is allow you to join multiple tables as long as they have a relationship (or a column that is present on both tables with the same value). In your case table_1 corresponds to table_2 which corresponds to table_3. To get data that is on table_3 you can simply do the following.

```sql
SELECT table_1.user_id, table_3.price
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.serial = table_2.serial
JOIN table_3
    ON table_2.product_id = table_3.product_id
WHERE table_1.user_id = 35;
```

This will return

```
user_id | price
--------|------
35      | 10
```

In PHP the query would look the same except it needs to be a string. This is how I like making it:

```php
$sql = "SELECT table_1.user_id, table_3.price ";
$sql .= "FROM table_1 ";
$sql .= "JOIN table_2 ";
$sql .= "ON table_1.serial = table_2.serial ";
$sql .= "JOIN table_3 ";
$sql .= "ON table_2.product_id = table_3.product_id ";
$sql .= "WHERE table_1.user_id = 35";
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you. Will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: I assume you'd end up with 10, by starting with the ID 35 using this method. It compares each table and finds the match?

Comment: @Michael, the way this query is set it will pull all the records on the tables. In order to only pull what you are looking for you have to add a `WHERE` clause in the query. `WHERE table_1.user_id = 35`

Comment: Thanks would you add it as a final line, or before 'From Table_1' ?

Comment: @Michael, it'll be the final line. Make sure the line before that one has a blank space at the end because if not PHP thinks it's just big long line with no spaces.

Comment: to confirm you mean : $sql .= "ON table_2.product_id = table_3.product_id" 
 WHERE "table_1.user_id = 35 "

Comment: @Michael, here I edited the answer to match what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a `JOIN`. For example

```
select 
    table_1.user_id, table_3.price 
from table_1 
    left join table_2 on table_1.serial=table_2.serial 
    left join table_3 on table_2.product_id=table_3.product_id
```

Comment: Argh thanks very much. Simple. Think I'm good to go. How would you present it in php